# exit() function creates 500 error (Google App Engine & Python 2.7)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I created a function which checks parameters and decide to run the rest of the code. I looks like:

```
def assert_something(a):
    if a>3:
        exit(0)
```

I try to use this something like:

```
class SomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,parameter):
        #check and if something wrong then quit
        assert_something(parameter)

        #otherwise do other things
```

the problem is `exit()` function always creates a response with 500 code.

How can modify this code so that I can exit from this request with 200 code for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since you are using a framework a lot of things happens under the hood,  for example after one of your handlers returns the headers and other information is sent to the browser. But when you exit you interrupt the normal flow hence the internal Server Error.

What you could do is to have a decorator that asserts that the parameter is valid. Note that still you should provide the user with something useful in case the parameter is invalid.

The decorator could be something like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def assert_something(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
    if args[1] > 3: #args[0] is self, args[1] is parameter. Better to use kwargs
      return None
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  return wrapper
```

And then use it as:

```
@assert_something
def get(self, parameter):
  ...
```

Comment: first I need to get **integer or string** as a parameter not a function.

I tried this code by creating additional function `f` but did not work. It still returns to the `def get(self,parameter):` function and executes the rest of the code.

Comment: What do you mean by need to get integer or string as a parameter not a function? Also, you need to apply the decorator to your get method, as shown by the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use return instead:

```
def everything_ok(a):
  return a <= 3

class SomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,parameter):
        if not everything_ok(parameter)
           #if you want to return something
           #self.response.out.write("")
           return

        #do something else
```

Comment: thanks, this is also possible but as I said to @Hoffman, I have to call this function several times, therefore I needed to learn an alternative and simpler way.

Comment: What do you mean with "simpler"?
Why can't my function be called several times?
I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: Of course we can call it several times, yet checking and returning several times seems to me repetition. I wondered if there is a way exiting from anywhere other than `get` function. But still you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exit(), that will raise an error as you have found.

You need to construct a valid response (it could be empty).

Have a read of http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html

And if you need to return some sort of HTTP error, you will still need to construct a valid response.

Comment: What I am asking is how can construct a valid response and exit at the same time.

Comment: Have you read the docs I provided the link too? returning a valid response (or even a blank return is all you need to do.)  A valid response is an empty response with a http status error set for instance.

Comment: I read and I see what you mean, but I can do this only in the `get(self,parameter):` function by returning a value from `assert_something(a)` and checking the result it again in the `get` function. However, I have to call `assert_something(a)` function many times, so I need to create an empty response directly from `assert_something(a)` rather than returning a boolean result to check again and again.

Comment: If you take the other persons answer Sebastian Kreft and use decorators to do the assertion then you can return directly from the assert_seomthing wrapper with a valid response without going further into you get handler. And you can stack decorators.

Comment: I am relatively new in python and GAE and I never used decorators before. I have to work to implement what you said, I hope it works.